# I used Magento2.1.7 get error image "404 error: Page not found." about "pub/media"

Tags: image, magento-2.1.7, 404, media-images

My link is SSL HTTPS  "https: //www.sample.com/pub/media/eby/tmpteone/store/images/bannerxinpin.jpg" ,picture can not loading on "pub/media/mypicture"

Get error "404 error: Page not found."

Can you help me? thank you guys!!!

i used "php bin/magento catalog:images:resize" "php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy" still not work to me.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a permission for media, run below command from the terminal in the root project folder:

```
chmod -Rf 777 pub/media
```